# send/get variable from .php to .php

Tags: php, send

I have a "first.php" file with a "$value" variable and I want send it to a "second.php" file, the files don't have a view (html), are just "controller files" and both files are in the same folder. Please, if you have the answer, be specific, I am a beginner.

This is de first.php file:

```
<?php

  $value = "hello";

?>
```

And this is the second.php file

```
<?php

   //and here I need to use de first.php $value variable

?>
```

Comment: How do you imagine the sending be? Do you first go to `first.php` and it will redirect you to `second.php` with `$value` now displayed or do you go directly to `second.php` and `$value` is displayed?

Comment: There are multiple ways to pass around variable data in PHP without using any forms but this will depend primarily on your requirements.

Comment: Perhaps do everyone a favor and answer what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: My question was answered by KIKO, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `include()` in the first php file, like so:

```
<?php

  $value = "hello";

  include('second.php');

?>
```

this will make the variable `$value` available in the second php file. There are other ways of doing this, but your question is lacking your reason for wanting to do this. I have a feeling you're trying to do something for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I know that it is a wrong way, just I need it.

Comment: Well, if it helps... Alternatively you could include the first php file at the top of the second one, the result is, more or less, the same. The difference is the file you need to execute to get the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the variable so

```
<?php
   $value = "hello";
   include("second.php");
```

Or in the first file.php

```
<?php
  $value = "hello";
  echo "<a href='second.php?variable=".$value."'>Pasar variable</a>";
```

And in the second file receive the variable of the next shape for the method GET

```
<?php
  $variable = $_GET['variable'];
  echo "Value from first.php: ".$variable;
```